# Show that $f(z)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ is not analytic at $(0,0)$ even though the Cauchy Riemann conditions are satisfied there.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=\sqrt{|xy|}$, how do I find the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$? How can we show it is not analytic at $(0,0)$?

Comment: $\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert}$ isn't even real-differentiable in $0$.

Comment: @Daniel, can you help me prove that mathematically?

Comment: The partial derivatives are both $0$. But on the line $x = y$, you have a kink, like the real absolute value function.

Comment: @JonathanY. Complex differentiability is real differentiability + CR. Partial differentiability + CR, as is the case here, is not enough: $$\frac{f(t(1+i))}{t(1+i)} = \frac{\sqrt{2t^2}}{t(1+i)} = \pm \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\neq \lim_{t\searrow 0} \frac{f(t)}{t} = 0$$ for real $t$, so $f$ is not complex differentiable in $0$.

Comment: @JonathanY. I didn't mean to belittle it. However, to show $f$ is not analytic at $0$, it is sufficient to show that it isn't even complex differentiable in $0$. And to show that, it is sufficient to show that it isn't even real differentiable in $0$. Each condition is weaker than the preceding, so if even the weaker condition isn't satisfied, the stronger is a fortiori not satisfied. With what word should that be expressed if "even" carries wrong connotations?

Comment: @Daniel appologies, I seem to be working through a language barrier, and I'm not getting my point across. Let me try again: (a) this exercise seems to be designed specifically to demonstrate how CR-at-a-point isn't a sufficient condition for complex differntiability. (b) As we've noted, in general complex differentiability is nothing more than real differentiability with the added requirement that the differential be a multiplication by a complex number (AKA CR equation). (c) Since in this case CR does hold, real differentiability is *exactly* what one should look at, no more, but no less.

Comment: @JonathanY. Maybe it is about complex differentiability, that makes sense. However, the title and body speak of analyticity, and that is a much stronger thing, and my first comment said basically "It's not real differentiable, hence not complex differentiable, let alone analytic", it didn't occur to me that perhaps the word analytic was used where complex differentiable was meant.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh my; I just assumed so (because one would expect that to be the point of the exercise), without ever noting the term that was actually used. (This is what happens when I assume things.)

Answer (score 6):

In the real case $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {|f(h,0)|}{|h|}=0=\frac {|f(0,h)|}{|h|}$ hence if it is differentiable at $0$ the derivative would be $0$ (Since if $f$ where differentiable the derivative would be the partial derivatives in a matrix)  but $\lim_{(h,h)\to 0}\frac{|f(h,h)-f(0,0)-0|}{|(h,h)|}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}$ which mean the limit $\lim_{(h,k)\to 0}\frac{|f(h,k)-f(0,0)-0|}{|(h,k)|}$ is not $0$ which shows $f$ is not real differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @user128964 if you like user10444's answer, consider accepting it. If you'd like to see something more, don't be shy about asking for it ;)