# Cauchy Riemann equations.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there function $\mathcal f:\mathbb C \to\mathbb C $ , $ f = u+iv $ , such that $ \mathcal u_x,u_y,v_x $ and $ \mathcal v_y$ exist and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations at (0,0) but $ \mathcal f $ is not differentiable at (0,0)?

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x+iy) = \sqrt{|x||y|}$.

**Edit:** For solution [Show that $f(z)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ is not analytic at $(0,0)$ even though the Cauchy Riemann conditions are satisfied there.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678486/show-that-fz-sqrtxy-is-not-analytic-at-0-0-even-though-the-cauchy-r)

Comment: At (0,0) does not satisfy C.R.E.

Comment: It does,note that partial derivatives are just zero.